# What Android app can I use to contol my BLE esp32?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on controlling my ESP32 aka (Heltec ESP32 Lora) via my android phone using BLE.

I'm following the code used in this youtube video which seems pretty staraight forward. But he uses an IPhone app. I haven't been able to find any android apps that work without connection issues.

https://youtu.be/O06UhBXRjws

Does anyone have any idea of what Android BLE contol apps that might work?

Comment: There are multiple apps I've used without connection issues. For example [nRF Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=de&gl=US) or [LightBlue](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.punchthrough.lightblueexplorer&hl=de&gl=US)

Comment: Awesome!! LightBlue did the trick. Thanks !!